# How do I send money from imported keys to my localbitcoin wallet?

Tags: wallet, multibit, localbitcoins

Okay, I imported keys from my desktop to MultiBit, it took a while, now I have got a file on my desktop, when I open it with notepad there is like: "receive, *walletadress", receive *walletadress*" etc.

Now, could you please tell me how to send money from these wallets to my current main wallet on localbitcoins?

Comment: I have the same question and the point is that transferring to local bitcoin from another wallet like Exodus requires some fee for example 17$ for my current amount

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there is no need for importing your private keys anywhere else if you want to keep them **safe** and **inaccessible by third parties** such as localbitcoins.info. You can simply create **Output transaction** from your desktop PC from MultiBit wallet to the public key that is presented in your account on localbitcoins.info.

For more information how to create transaction follow guide from [Multibit - Send bitcoins](https://multibit.org/en/help/v0.5/help_sendingBitcoin.html)

Answer (score 0):

Log into localbitcoins. Find your deposit address and then send from multibit as per the link marek posted.